# Password error is always true react-hook-form

Tags: react-native, react-hook-form

I'm trying to make a login in react-native with react-hook-form, but when I come to the login screen the console.log(errors) puts out this line `password: {type: "required", message: "Password is required", ref: {…}}`

and i don't understand why.

this is my code:

```
const Login = () => {
  const { control, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      username: '',
      password: ''
    }
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data)
  }
    
  return (
      <View>
        <Controller
          defaultValue=""
          name={fields.username}
          control={control}
          render={({ onChange, value }) => (
          <TextInput
            onChange={onChange}
            value={value}
            placeholder='Username'
            rules={{ required: { value: true, message: 'Username is required' } }}
          />
          )}
        />
        {errors.username && <Text>UserName is required.</Text>}
        <Controller
          defaultValue=""
          name={fields.password}
          control={control}
          rules={{
            required: { value: true, message: 'Password is required' },
            minLength: {
              message: 'Use at least 4 characters.',
              value: 4,               
            },
          }}
          render={({ onChange, value }) => (
          <TextInput
            onChange={onChange}
            value={value}
            secureTextEntry={true}
            placeholder='Password'
          />
          )}
        />
        {errors.password?.type === "required" && <Text>Password is required.</Text>}
        
        {errors.password?.type === "minLength" && <Text>Minimum 4 characters are required</Text>}
        {console.log(errors)}
        <Button title='Submit' onPress={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} />
      </View>
  )
}

export default Login;
```

I'm not sure were the error is, I hope someone can help with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `onChangeText` prop instead of `onChange` to receive the current typed input value.

One other minor note:
The first `<Controller />` misses the `rules` as you placed it as a prop for the `<TextInput />`. I corrected it in the CodeSandbox.

[image: Edit RHF - React Native]

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer, the reason I used onChange instead of onChangeText was because in react-hook-form docs it said to write it like this onChangeText={(value) => onChange(value)} instead of onChangeText={onchange} and it kept telling me that onchange wasn't a function

Comment: Ok. But you were able to resolve it with the provided CodeSandbox?

Comment: Yes the CodeSandbox helped a lot, thank you